# Implementing Custom WebView in Xamarin for POST request

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have found a guide how to implement custom webview in Xamarin.

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    Action<string> action;

    public static readonly BindableProperty PostUrlProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PostUrl), typeof(string), typeof(CustomWebView), string.Empty, BindingMode.OneWay);

    public string PostUrl
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PostUrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PostUrlProperty, value); }
    }

    public byte[] PostData { get; set; } = new byte[0];


    public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
    {
        action = callback;
    }

    public void Cleanup()
    {
        action = null;
    }

    public void InvokeAction(string data)
    {
        if (action == null || data == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        action.Invoke(data);
    }
}
```

Android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
```

namespace ActivaChatOnWebView.Droid.Renderer
{
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
{
}

```
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "PostUrl") //e.PropertyName is never PostUrl
        {
            if (Control == null)
                return;

            Android.Webkit.WebView web = Control;
            CustomWebView view = Element as CustomWebView;
            web.PostUrl(view.PostUrl, view.PostData);
        }
    }
}
```

}

MainPage

```
 System.Text.Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        string url = "myUrl";
hybridWebView.PostData = bytes;
        hybridWebView.PostUrl = url;
```

MainPge.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

<renderer:CustomWebView x:Name="hybridWebView"/>

I cannot get **e.PropertyName is PostUrl**

What i am missing ? :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you put the `hybridWebView.PostUrl = url` in the MainPage's construction method?

I have done a sample to test and found the MainPage's construction method will execute before the HybridWebViewRenderer's. So the `OnElementPropertyChanged` method will not be invoked before the `hybridWebView.PostUrl = url` completed.

I created a button and put the `hybridWebView.PostUrl = url` into the button clicked event. And then I get `e.PropertyName == "PostUrl"` when I click the button. So you can have a try.